# Expressing $ \frac{\cos x + \sin x}{\cos x - \sin x} $ as a single trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

For a while now, I have been trying to get this expression into 1 term instead of the 2 term fraction.
$$
\frac{\cos x + \sin x}{\cos x - \sin x}
$$
The most I have gotten down to is get it to a single ratio, ie,
$$
\frac{1 + \tan x}{1 - \tan x}
$$

I have been looking for an identity or formula of some sort to factorize $ \cos x + \sin x $ and $ \cos x - \sin x $.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: But I dont see an *equation* to solve!

Comment: Think about $\tan(a+b)$

Comment: In my opinion, $\frac{1+\tan x}{1- \tan x}$ is already pretty neat. I don't know why you would need to simplify it further. Here's what Wolfram Alpha comments: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2Btan+x%29%2F%281-tan+x%29

Comment: I used tan(a + b) on the question which I solved just before this one and my mind went blank after that I guess. I don't know why I did not think of it earlier. Thank you, it helped me a lot!

Comment: If you are satisfied with any of the answers below, consider accepting it by clicking the tick mark button next to the answer. Doing so will award reputation points to you and the answerer for taking the time out to help you. If you are not satisfied, please feel free to comment on their answers and ask for clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$
\dfrac{\cos x + \sin x}{\cos x - \sin x} = \dfrac{1+ \tan x}{1 - \tan x}
$

Now, $\tan (x+y) = \dfrac{\tan x+ \tan y}{1 - \tan x \tan y}$

Therefore,  $\tan (x+ \frac{\pi}{4}) = \dfrac{\tan x+ 1}{1 - \tan x}$

Therefore, $\dfrac{\cos x + \sin x}{\cos x - \sin x} = \tan(x+ \frac{\pi}{4})$

Is this what you meant by 1 term?.

Comment: Yep this is exactly what I was thinking of. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @MrAtomic you can accept this answer if it was the most helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You may write it as $\tan(\pi/4+x)$, which is a single term.